# UITableViewCell with UIImage scaling performance

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

The UITableViewCell has UIImage to be displayed within it.

Images are obtained from the server, and stored in NSDictionary as NSData.

This image is resized for non-retina devices using UIImageGraphicsBeginImageContext as listed below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            static NSString *cellID=@"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
            NSDictionary *myDictionary=[self.tableObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSData *imgData=[myDictionary objectForKey:@"icon"];
            UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if(isRetina]){
                cell.iconImageView.image=img;
            }else{
                CGRect imgRect=CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width/2.0, img.size.height/2.0);
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgRect.size);
                [img drawInRect:imgRect];
                UIImage *newImg=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                cell.iconImageView.image=newImg;
            }
}
```

Would it be better approach and less memory intensive or should store it in the disk, and then access the image from it and assign it to cell.iconImageView.image;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write it to disk when you download it.

that way, os can lazy read the data, cache it and you dont have the image data in memory all the time

Comment: Even I feel the same, but I was worried about the performance of reading the image from the disk in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: But, it takes considerably long time to read it from the disk, than it was in the app. itself which uses [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];